# are geodesics continuous as a mapping?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, geodesic

Suppose we have a manifold $M$, with a metric(or connection).
Suppose $p$ is a point and $v \in T_p(M)$. 
Then there is a geodesic $\gamma$ starting at $p$ such that $\gamma'(0) = v$.

Now imagine $\gamma(t) = q$ and $q \in U$.

The question is whether for $v'$ very close to $v$ and $p'$ very close to $p$
the geodesic starting at $p'$ with velocity $v'$ will pass through $U$ or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

The standard existence and uniqueness theorem for systems of linear ODE's (which is what one uses to construct geodesics to begin with) has a strong version in which the conclusion says that integral curves depend continuously on initial conditions. In the application of that theorem to construction of geodesics, the initial conditions are precisely $p$ and $\gamma'(0)$.

Comment: Thanks where can I see the strong version?

Comment: I learned it in Spivak's "Differential Geometry". I suspect that it is common among differential equations books as well, but I cannot say for sure.

Comment: If the Christoffel symbols for a given metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ are $\Gamma^\rho_{\mu \nu}$, the geodesic equation becomes $\ddot x^\rho + \Gamma^\rho_{\mu \nu} \dot x^\mu \dot x^\nu = 0$, which follows from $\nabla_X X = 0$ (the same equation written in coordinate-free form), which is manifestly non-linear due to the presence of $X$  both as the "deriving" and "derived" vector field.  (Here $X = (\dot x^1, \dot x^2, \ldots, \dot x^n$.)   But though the assertion in this answer that the geodesic equations are linear is incorrect, the proof I think can be made to fly in the non-linear case.

Comment: The theorem which supports the desired result, that solutions depend continuously on initial conditions and parameters, which holds for both linear and non-linear ODEs, may be found for instance in Hale's *Ordinary Differential Eqauations* or Witold Hurewic's *Lectures* on same.

Comment: My apologies, I did indeed misremember the issue of linearity. Regarding references to Spivak's "Differential Geometry Vol. 1", the required theorem about solutions to 2nd order ODE's, including continuous dependence on initial conditions, is put into exercise 4 of chapter 5, on page 169 of Spivak. The geodesic differential equation itself (in the comment of @RobertLewis) is found on page 329 of Spivak.